# public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) gives error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase and this line of code results in an error.

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
}
```

The errors are as below,

1. Method does not override method from its superclass
2. Method 'onCancelled(com.firebase.client.FirebaseError)' is never used

How to resolve these errors?

My code -

```
public class FirebaseClient  {
    Context c;
    String DB_URL;
    ListView listView;
    Firebase firebase;
    ArrayList<Dog> dogies= new ArrayList<>();
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    public  FirebaseClient(Context c, String DB_URL, ListView listView)
    {
        this.c= c;
        this.DB_URL= DB_URL;
        this.listView= listView;
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(c);
        firebase=new Firebase(DB_URL);
    }
    public  void refreshdata()
    {
        firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getupdates(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                getupdates(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    public void getupdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        dogies.clear();

        for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Dog d= new Dog();
            d.setTimestamp(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getTimestamp());
            d.setInstituteNotice(ds.getValue(Dog.class).getInstituteNotice());
            dogies.add(d);
        }
        if(dogies.size()>0)
        {
            customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(c, dogies);
            listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) customAdapter);
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [legacy Firebase SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) (which has been deprecated for more than a year) and mixing in classes from the new SDK. You should consider migrating to the new SDK.  The [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) outlines the steps.

In the code you posted, [DatabaseError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError) is from the new SDK, not the legacy SDK, so this override is not valid and should be removed:

```
 @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you need to remove the following method from your code:

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
```

You are already overriding `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)` from its superclass. The code that i adviced you to be removed was used in ealier version of SDK. You need to use the new one.